# Bash redirection: named pipes and EOF

Tags: bash, named-pipes, io-redirection, process-substitution

Take the following code:

```
rm -f pipe
mkfifo pipe

foo () {
    echo 1
    sleep 1
    echo 2
}

#1
exec 3< <(foo &)
cat <&3 # works

#2
foo >pipe &
cat <pipe # works

#3
exec 3<>pipe
foo >&3 &
cat <&3 # hangs

#4 -- update: this is the correct approach for what I want to do
foo >pipe &
exec 3<pipe
rm pipe
cat <&3 # works
```

Why does approach #3 hang, while others do not? Is there a way to make approach #3 not hang?

Rationale: I wish to use quasi-unnamed pipes to connect several asynchronously running subprocesses, for this I need to delete the pipe after making a file descriptor point to it:

```
mkfifo pipe
exec {fd}<>pipe
rm pipe
# use &$fd only
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in approach 3 is that the FIFO `pipe` then has 2 writers: The bash script (because you have opened it read/write by using `exec 3<>`) and the sub-shell running `foo`. You'll read EOF when all writers have closed the file descriptor. One writer (the sub-shell running `foo`) will exit fairly quickly (after roughly 1s) and therefore close the file descriptor. The other writer however (the main shell) only closes the file descriptor when it'd exit as there's no closes of file descriptor `3` anywhere. But it can't exit because it waits for the `cat` to exit first. That's a deadlock:

- `cat` is waiting for an EOF
- the EOF only appears when the main shell closes the fd (or exits)
- the main shell is waiting for `cat` to terminate

Therefore you'll never exit.

Case 2 works because the pipe only ever has one writer (the sub-shell running `foo`) which exits very quickly, therefore an EOF will be read. In case 1, there's also only ever one writer because you open fd 3 read-only (`exec 3<`).

**EDIT**: Remove nonsense about case 4 not being correct (see comments). It's correct because the writer can't exit before the reader connects because it'll also be blocked when opening the file when the reader isn't opening yet. <s>The newly added case 4 is unfortunately incorrect. It's racy and only works iff `foo` doesn't terminate (or close the pipe) before `exec 3<pipe` runs.</s>

Also check the [`fifo(7)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/fifo) man page:

> The kernel maintains exactly one pipe object for each FIFO special file that is opened by at least one process. The FIFO must be opened on both ends (reading and writing) before data can be passed. Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.

Comment: Nailed it. `exec 3<>` makes the main shell a writer, which causes the EOF problem.

Comment: @Irfy I added that. In case 1, the file descriptor 3 is opened read-only in the main shell. Therefore the pipe will never have more than 1 writer.

Comment: With the help of that, I rewrote my code that removes the pipe, so that it works as expected, thanks.

Comment: @Irfy unfortunately, #4 is also not really correct. It's actually a race condition: If `foo` exits before `exec 3<pipe` runs, `exec 3<pipe` will hang until another writer opens `pipe`.

Comment: I cannot provoke a problem as you describe it. Can you try? Add `sleep 2` after `foo >pipe &` -- nothing changes, and foo has most definitely terminated. [GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release]

Comment: The only problem that I see is `exec 3<pipe` hanging before there is a writer -- or after `pipe` contents have been consumed (until another writer writes to it).

Comment: @Irfy ah true, you're right! The writer (`foo >pipe `) only starts running when the reader (`exec 3<pipe`) connects. So you're all good. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Irfy fixed that in the answer as well.